# Check valid url before reporting 405 for detail view in Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, http, django-rest-framework, httpresponse

I have a ViewSet that looks like this:

```
class BoardViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, ...):
    @detail_route(methods=["post"])
    def register(self, request, pk):
        board = self.get_object()
        ...
```

I get the following results, when I make these requests:

```
POST /board/1234/register -> 200
POST /board/BEEF/register -> 404 NOT FOUND
GET  /board/1234/register -> 405 NOT ALLOWED
GET  /board/BEEF/register -> 405 NOT ALLOWED
```

It's the last item in the list that concerns me. Performing a GET request on an invalid URL returns the NOT ALLOWED response, not the NOT FOUND response, even though that's an invalid URL. I understand why this happens, in terms of how Django and the DRF's routing works. My question is twofold:

1. Is this the appropriate behavior, in terms of HTTP response code semantics?
2. If not, is there a (good) way to fix this?

Comment: you can only send post request to `register` method. 
also post your URLS.

Comment: Interesting question. Is there a reason why you see it as a problem that the request method is validated before the url itself is checked? From my perspective this is the appropriate behaviour, because if the view doesn't accept the request method, there is no point in checking if the url is valid, but I'm interested in other opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the appropriate behavior, in terms of HTTP response code semantics?

Well, you only accept POST methods on the "/board/([^/.]+)/register" url so it seems legit to return a 405 status code.

> If not, is there a (good) way to fix this?

You should set the views' `lookup_value_regex` more specific so it only matches the ID you expect. With that, if that url regex doesn't match, it'll skip that view and move on, ultimately ending with a 404.

Comment: `BEEF` is a bad example; I only used it to emphasize that this is a non-existent key. I'm looking for a solution where the key is *possibly* valid.

Comment: I suppose it's better to `405` than `404`, since the latter requires a database query.

Comment: @Lucretiel then you need to enable GET and handle the response code by yourself.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to expect a 404 on an url that doesn't accept the associated verb through. 404 means that the entry point does understand the verb which goes against what your code says.